# Need advice: Rigging 2D wing

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm trying to rig this 2D wing to animate it as if it was flapping like a real wing.

So I imported the SVG and converted it to a mesh.

**1.** I tried to use bendy bones but the result is not satisfying and makes the edges look broken and jaggy ([see gif here](https://media.giphy.com/media/3ov9karjFnoigE8XhS/giphy.gif))

**2.**  I tried to rig the entire wing with bones, but I don't know how to make one bone move the others with it, so I don't have to move individual bones one by one.

Here's a [link to the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7PwkpiwRtW7OU9OYXliWXBNWDQ/view?usp=sharing)... I'll be super happy to hear your advice! :)

Thanks,
Netanel.

[image]

Comment: Please include a link to something that is similar to the result you desire. Please show your work in movie format or gif. We should see some motion in your example, whether it meets your standards or not.  If you feel you need assistance in producing motion, a suggestion is to see a video tutorial series. Show the contrast between what you have accomplished and what is the desired result.

Comment: Video tutorial series.  Bones.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvG39bGEsKI&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS&index=35  .  You can inspect and determine if you would benefit from watching the whole series.  You have not explicitly asked for a tutorial.  Beginners and many others can benefit greatly from a tutorial series.  Typically this site is not focused on tutorial information.  Video can do a useful job for tutorials.

Comment: Objects converted from curves have bad topology, they are not good for animation. Try re-modelling it with clean topology